# Pure HTML/CSS Vertical Char won't appear on Email Content when sent through Sahi Pro

Tags: html, css, email, charts, sahi

In my automatic email which is 100% functional and responsive I have a simple HTML table which works 100% with the following code:

```
'<html lang="en">' +
    '<head>' +
        '<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">' +
    '</head>' +
    '<body>' +
        '<table class="table" style="width: 75%; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; margin-left: 95px; display: block;">' +
        '<thead>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<th scope="col">ID:</th>' +
            '<th scope="col">Test Status:</th>' +
            '<th scope="col">Project Name / Server:</th>' +
            '<th scope="col">Report Test Description:</th>' +
            '<th scope="col">Browser:</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<th style="color: #3333ff;">' + IDcounter() + '</th>' +
            $testStatusMessageColor_1 +
            '<td>' + $projName + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $functions_1 + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $browserStatus + '</td>' +
            '</tr><tr>' +
            '<th style="color: #3333ff;">' + $IDcounter + '</th>' +
            $testStatusMessageColor_2 +
            '<td>' + $projName + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $functions_2 + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $browserStatus + '</td>' +
            '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>' +
        '</table>' +
    '</body>' +
'</html>' +
```

Although, when I decided to add another display such as the previously mentioned HTML/CSS Chart Graphic, it simply doesn't show up...

Code:

```
'<html>' +
    '<head>' +
      '<style type="text/css">' +
  'body {font: 13px/1.3 "Lucida Grande",sans-serif; color: #666;}' +
  '.chart {display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 60%; max-width: 700px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 2%); background-size: 100% 50px; background-position: left top;}' +
  '.chart li {position: relative; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; height: 200px;}' +
  '.chart span {margin: 0 1em; display: block; background: rgba(209, 236, 250, 0.75); animation: draw 1s ease-in-out;}' +
  '.chart span:before {position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 100%; padding: 5px 1em 0; display: block; text-align: center; content: attr(title); word-wrap: break-word;}' +

  '@keyframes draw {0% {height: 0;}}' +
      '</style>' +
    '</head>' +
  '<body>' +
    '<ul class="chart">' +
      '<li>' +
        '<span style="height:100%" title="Column 1"></span>' +
      '</li>' +
      '<li>' +
        '<span style="height:80%" title="Column 2"></span>' +
      '</li>' +
    '</ul>' +
  '</body>' +
'</html>' +
```

I believe it might be because CSS language isn't supported (because in a browser, the Chart Graphic works 100%, but not within the Email Body Message)... what can I do about this?

Comment: You could start by giving us a proper executable example, so that we can see what this is supposed to look like in the browser in the first place. (Not going to create one myself by breaking apart your string concatenation construction here …)

Comment: Expecting keyframe animations to work might be overly ambitious too begin with though, depending on what mail clients/ web interfaces you need this to work in.

Comment: @misorude yes, of course: https://codepen.io/Victa/embed/xDqbf?height=450&theme-id=0&slug-hash=xDqbf&default-tab=result&user=Victa&embed-version=2&preview=true#result-box I utilized this graph and simply reduced from 4 columns to 2.

Comment: Hm, I’d try to remove the animation component from that first, to see if the static end result works at least.

Comment: @misorude I removed the animation, but sadly the result is exactly the same... Any other suggestions that you might suggest me to fix this issue?

Comment: Try and inline _all_ the styles, instead of using a <style> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.

Keyframe sadly won't work in email-clients as well as a lot of over advanced css-properties.

To fix this, you might want to use an image of the chart. Something like [Image-Charts](http://image-charts.com) to send charts through email, it's free, it will work on every browser & email client **and** will be animated (thanks to gif!).

```
https://image-charts.com/chart
    ?cht=p3
    &chs=700x200
    &chd=t:60,40
    &chl=Hello|World
    &chan
    &chf=ps0-0,lg,45,ffeb3b,0.2,f44336,1|ps0-1,lg,45,8bc34a,0.2,009688,1
```

[image: a]

Comment: Whoa! Just tried this feature and it works flawlessly! I'm speechless! Thank you so much for introducing me to this easy chart generator =)